# fetchPage returns empty

Tags: javascript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am fetching using fetch page

```
const reqname = request.query.search;

const result = await this.users.where('name', reqname).fetchPage({
     limit: 1,
     offset: 0
})
return response.json(result);
```

For example, the `request.query.search` has a value of `Juan`,

I successfully getting a result with a user whose name is `Juan`

but when I change `Juan` to `Peter` I'm not getting a result, thus it just returns an empty array,

but I have a user on database whose name is `Peter`.

It is weird because i have on database both of the user.

Comment: Maybe you don't have that exact string in a name. If you get the result you want in one case and not in another then it's 99% certainly something wrong with your code and/or data.

Comment: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/2052